# GLSL shader incorrectly shading a plane

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a light source illuminating a plane defined as

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertexAttrib3f(attribLoc, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); // need to specify only once since the 
                                            // normal at all 4 vertexs' are the same
    glVertex3f(-200.0, -200.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(200.0, -200.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(200.0, 200.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(-200.0, 200.0, 0.0);
glEnd();
```

the fragment shader calculates only diffuse component. Everything works well when the light source
is in front of the plane. When I move the light source behind the plane, 
I still see a point of light.  I would expecting "0" diffuse contribution at every pixel in this case.

The diplay, reshape, and shaders ...

```
void display(void){
    int attribLoc;
    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0.0, 1.0, 10.0);   

    shader.bind();
    attribLoc = glGetAttribLocation(shader.id(), "app_to_vertex_normal"); 

    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader.id(), "LightPos"), 0.0, 0.0, -2.0);

    // Setting the Material properties
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader.id(), "mdiffuse"), 0.6, 0.6, 0.6); 

    // Setting the Light properties
    glUniform3f(glGetUniformLocation(shader.id(), "ldiffuse"), 0.6, 0.6, 0.6); 

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertexAttrib3f(attribLoc, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); 

    glVertex3f(-200.0, -200.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(200.0, -200.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(200.0, 200.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(-200.0, 200.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();
    shader.unbind();

    glutSwapBuffers();
    }

    void reshape(int w, int h){
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-300.0, 300.0, -300.0, 300.0, 5.0, 20.0); //(Perspective)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    }

The Vertex shader
    #version 140
    in vec3 app_to_vertex_normal;
    out vec3 vertex_to_fragment_normal;
    out vec3 vertex_in_eye_coord;

    void main() {            
    // Set the position of the current vertex 
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;

    vertex_in_eye_coord = vec3(gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex);


    vertex_to_fragment_normal = gl_NormalMatrix*app_to_vertex_normal;

}


The fragment shader
#version 140

in vec3 vertex_to_fragment_normal;
in vec3 vertex_in_eye_coord;

uniform vec3 LightPos;

// Material properties 
uniform vec3 mdiffuse;

// Light properties 
uniform vec3 ldiffuse;

void main() {
vec3 vertex_to_light;
vec3 norm;

float diffuse_mult;
vec3 diffuse_comp;


// Diffuse component 
norm = normalize(vertex_to_fragment_normal);
vertex_to_light = normalize(LightPos-vertex_in_eye_coord);
diffuse_mult = max(dot(vertex_to_light, norm), 0.0);
diffuse_comp = diffuse_mult*ldiffuse*mdiffuse;  


gl_FragColor = vec4(diffuse_comp, 1.0); 

}
```

Comment: `LightPos` is probably in world-space rather than eye-space. And a variable called `norm` should probably be a `float` since in linear algebra, *norm* means length; consider renaming that variable to `normal` to avoid confusion.

Comment: I transformed the LightPos in the vertex shader by multiplying by the gl_ModelViewMatrix and then passed it via an 'out' variable to fragment shader. Then used that instead of LightPos. 
I still see the same behaviour

Comment: Try outputting each component of the lighting equation as the frag color. Do the normals display as you expect? Try doing the lighting calculations in world space in-case you made any mistakes transforming LightPos. Also, some screenshots would be helpful.

Comment: i've checked the normal (via frag color) and intermediate components. They seem to be correct. The dot product (dot(vertex_to_light, norm)) always returns a +ve number which I cannot explain

Comment: by setting gluLookAt(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0) i.e, eye position at (0,0.0) will the lighting calculations be done in world space ?